# php how to pass a string/variable to a function?

Tags: php, function

I have a file called function.php that has a function like this:

```
public function issue_challenge () 
{
    $conn= fns_connect(13);
    mysql_select_db("et_games",$conn);
    $sql = "insert into challengers (challenger,defender,stake,matching_game_id) values (".$this->talentnum_self.",".$this->talentnum_other.",".$this->stake.",'".$this->matching_str()."')";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    echo $sql; mysql_error();

    if($result){
        echo "ok.\n";return true;                
    }else{
        return false;                    
    }
}
```

and another file called test.php that has a form in it.

How do I pass the values from that form into that function?

I am looking for some generic answer on how to pass a string/variable to a function.

Thanks

Comment: `functionName('I am a string');` to pass a string, `functionName($iAmAVariable);` to pass a variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call your function this way:

```
 if(isset($_GET['form_name'])) {
     $val = $_GET['form_name'];
     public function issue_challenge($val);
}
```

Also: Change the declaration to:

```
public function issue_challenge($formValue) {

...function contents...

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Generic answer that increments a value:

> function inc($x) {
>
> ```
>  echo "x = " . $x;
>  $x++;
>  return $x;
> ```
>
> }
>
> function main() {
>
> ```
> $x = '1';
> $y = $this->inc($x);
> echo $y;
> ```
>
> }

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the form submission calls the function, then grab the value from the POST array. This is easier if using a php framework, many will offer you methods to clean the input. In this case since you are possibly using the input for a db query you will need to make sure it is properly escaped to avoid sql injection.

[PHP manaul for mysql_real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php)

```
<form action="issue_challenge" method="POST">
<input type="text" name="testInput" id="testInput"/>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>

public function issue_challenge () {
    $conn= fns_connect(13);
    $inputText = $_POST['testInput']
mysql_select_db("et_games",$conn);
    $sql = "insert into challengers (challenger,defender,stake,matching_game_id) values (".$this->talentnum_self.",".$this->talentnum_other.",".$this->stake.",'".$this->matching_str()."')";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    echo $sql; mysql_error();
        if($result){
            echo "ok.\n";return true;                
            }else{
                return false;                    
            }
}
```